# Mysql event to summarize a tables

Tags: php, mysql, events, procedure

I would like to create a daily event which I'd use to make an "insert into summarized_table SELECT [   ]". The event woul execute everydays at 10:00 am.

- This is the summarized table I will use to insert the data:

```
create table attemptsub_carrierday_sum (
    id              int(11) not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
    time        date    not null,
    country     int(11) not null,
    id_carrier  int(11) not null,
    attempts    int(11) not null,
    optins      int(11) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

- And this is the select I will use for the insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO attemptsub_carrierday_sum (time, country, id_carrier, attempts, optins) SELECT DATE(ahs.periodo) as time, co.id as country, ahs.id_carrier, SUM(ahs.attempts) as attempts, 
    SUM(case when ahs.api_code = 100 AND ahs.api_wasactive = 1 
        AND ahs.api_sending_short_code > 0
        then ahs.attempts else 0 end) as optins
    FROM `attemptsub_hourly_summarized` as ahs
    LEFT JOIN carrier as ca ON ahs.id_carrier= ca.id_carrier
    LEFT JOIN country as co ON ca.country_id = co.id
    GROUP BY co.id, ahs.id_carrier, time
    ORDER BY `time` DESC, country, id_carrier;
```

My problem is that I've never made and event in MySQL(I have done jobs in oracle but mysql is different) and I`d really appreciate your help.

If you need more information I will be pleased to help.

Comment: Is the documentation unclear? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Comment: Have you enabled `EVENT_SCHEDULER` ? `SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`.

Comment: I just realized that this is not the insert i Wold execute XD, is this one:  select DATE(att.created_at) as time ,co.id as country ,ca.id_carrier ,count(att.id) as attempts,
 sum(case when att.api_code = 100 AND att.api_wasactive=1 AND api_sending_short_code > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as optins
 from attemptsub as att
 LEFT JOIN carrier as ca ON att.id_carrier= ca.id_carrier
 LEFT JOIN country as co ON ca.country_id=co.id
  where created_at between curdate() - interval 2 day and curdate() - interval 1 day
 GROUP BY country,id_carrier,DATE(att.created_at)
    ORDER BY time desc, country, id_carrier

Comment: Hi CORRUPT, the event_scheduler is enabled. The Documentation is no unclear but as I dont have experience in mysql I would apreciate a litle of your help, thanks